# Elliptic PDE existence theorem for $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and consider the elliptic PDE
$$
\begin{align}
Lu = f
\quad &\textrm{in } \Omega, \\
u = 0 \quad &\textrm{on } \partial \Omega,
\end{align} \tag{1} \label{pde}$$
where $L$ is the elliptic operator
$$
Lu = -\sum_{i,j=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \Bigg( a_{ij} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \Bigg) 
+ \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} + a_0 u. \tag{2} \label{op}$$

Here we are assuming that $a_{ij}, a_i, a_0 \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and that the ellipticity condition holds:
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^N a_{ij}(x) \zeta_i \zeta_j \geq \alpha \vert\zeta\vert^2,
\quad \forall x \in \Omega, \quad \forall \zeta \in \mathbb{R}^N \textrm{ with } \alpha > 0.$$

Let $a(u,v)$ be the bilinear form corresponding to $\eqref{op}$.
Let $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$.
The weak formulation of $\eqref{pde}$ is:

$$\textrm{Find } u \in H_0^1(\Omega)
\textrm{ such that } a(u,v)=<f,v>_{H^{-1}, H_0^1} \textrm{ for all } v \in H_0^1(\Omega).
\tag{3} \label{pdew}
$$

Using Fredholm theory for compact operators, the following result is established in Theorem 9.23 of [1].

**Theorem 1.**
Suppose that the homogeneous equation associated to $\eqref{pdew}$, i.e. with $f = 0$, has $u = 0$ as its *unique* solution. Then for *every* $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ there *exists* a unique solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ of $\eqref{pdew}$.

*Proof sketch*.
The idea is to fix $\lambda > 0$ large enough that the bilinear form
$$a(u,v) + \lambda \int_{\Omega} uv$$
is coercive on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. Then, for every $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ there exists a unique $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$
a(u,v) + \lambda \int_{\Omega} uv = \int_{\Omega} fv \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

Setting $u = Tf$ we obtain a linear operator $T : L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$.
Since the injection $H_0^1(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$ is compact, the operator $T$ is compact.
Applying Fredholm's alternative we obtain the conclusion of Theorem 1. $\Box$

**My question: Is the following strengthened version of Theorem 1 true?** I have looked through some other PDE books (Evans, McOwen) and cannot seem to find an answer.

**Theorem 2.**
Suppose that the homogeneous equation associated to $\eqref{pdew}$, i.e. with $f = 0$, has $u = 0$ as its *unique* solution. Then for *every* $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ there *exists* a unique solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ of $\eqref{pdew}$.

---

[1]: *Brezis, Haim*, [**Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7), Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-70913-0/pbk; 978-0-387-70914-7/ebook). xiii, 599 p. (2011). [ZBL1220.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.46002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Let us denote by $A \colon H_0^1(\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega)$ your differential operator, i.e., we want to solve
$$
A u = f
$$
for $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Now, let $I \colon H_0^1(\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega)$ be defined via
$$
\langle I u, v\rangle := \int_\Omega u v \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
Then, $I$ is compact and for some $\lambda$ big enough, the operator $A + \lambda I$ is bijective (via Lax-Milgram). This shows that $A$ is a compact perturbation of a bijective operator and, thus, Fredholm with index $0$. Hence, injectivity of $A$ implies bijectivity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think this over and accept once I'm happy with it.